# Is it possible to get more precision in wireless signal strength?

Tags: c++, wifi, wireless, drivers

So in windows/linux, you are able to get a wireless hotspot's signal strength in dbms. For example, right now I have a signal strength of -64 dbms in my connection.

Now the problem I have is that the signal strength values I receive are always integers. For example, when I query the device for signal strength, it never gives me a value of -64.5 dbms.

My question is: what would be a good approach to get this precision? (OS does not matter). Should I be programming/modifying the drivers of my wireless transceiver? I don't really think that this is a limitation of the transceiver itself, but something somewhere is rounding the number.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect that the hardware is insufficiently accurate to support such precision.  Received power varies over such a massive range that accurate measurement is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After heavy research I realized that the problem is not *only* the driver. The device itself had limited capabilities of getting the signal strength. Most of regular wifi adapters do.